# Android Collection for First In All Out

Tags: android, collections, fifo

I have a problem where I need to use a type of collection in my android application. The collection should insert items at the top and will remove from the top too but also clear all the bottom most items from it.

For example, if I have following in the collection.

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

I insert "6".

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
```

I remove "6"

```
Empty
```

I insert "7"

```
7
```

And I insert "8"

```
7 | 8
```

Comment: If you are always removing from the top then why not just clear the structure every time? Maybe some clarification is in order here. Is order maintained as your sample seems to indicate?

Comment: This is one way to do that but how to make it thread safe as 2 different threads are responsible for inserting and removing.

Comment: Ahh maybe you should clarify your original question with all of your requirements. You also did not mention if maintaining order is required. As Peter mentioned a LinkedList can do this for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LinkedList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html) has all needed methods enabling you to add item to front or end of list. You can remove all with `clear()`.